# Calculus class problem [solved]

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, factorial

I was wondering how to determine whether this series converges:

$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(k+1)!}{k^k} \; ? $$

Here's how I started to tackle this problem:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\lim_{k \to \infty}{\left|\frac{\cfrac{(k+2)!}{(k+1)^{k+1}}}{\cfrac{(k+1)!}{k^k}}\right|} &= \frac{(k+2)!}{(k+1)^{k+1}} \times \frac{k^k}{(k+1)!} \\[0.6em]
&= \frac{k^k(k+2)!}{(k+1)^{k+1}(k+1)!} \\[0.6em]
&= \frac{k^k(k+2)(k+1)!}{(k+1)^{k+1}(k+1)!} \\[0.6em]
&= \frac{k^k(k+2)}{(k+1)^{k+1}} \\[0.6em]
&= \frac{k^k(k+2)}{(k+1)^k(k+1)} \\[0.6em]
&= \frac{k^k(k+2)}{(k+1)^k(k+1)} \\[0.6em]
\end{aligned}
$$

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You were on the right track.  I replaced your first image with math notation using [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and $\LaTeX$ syntax.  Have a look at my edit to see how it is done, and keep pursuing your ratio test.  You are almost there!

Comment: In your calculation, you're missing the "lim" operator before each expression after the first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Noting
$$ \lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{k^k}{(k+1)^k}=\lim_{k\to\infty}{(1+\frac1k)^{-k}}=e^{-1}$$
you have
$$ \lim_{k\to\infty}\bigg|\frac{{\frac{(k+2)!}{(k+1)^{k+1}}}}{\frac{(k+1)!}{k^k}}\bigg|=e^{-1}<1 $$
which implies that your series converges.

Comment: Thanks for all of your answers, this solved my problem! Our lecturer allows us to skip writing the lim operator every time to make our writing process a bit less intense.